# Is there AOP for Yii 2?

Tags: php, yii, yii2, aop, typo3-flow

I want to know how much time is executed every action. The easiest/ correct way would be to use AOP.

I'd like to have something like this:

```
/**
 * @FLOW3\Before("method(.*->action.*())")
 */
 public function markFirstTimeTag() {
// Do something here.
 }

 ...

 /**
 * @FLOW3\After("method(.*->action.*())")
 */
 public function markSecondTimeTag() {
// Do something here.
 }
```

I read about the [FLOW3](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/aspect-oriented-programming-in-php--net-24974) and this framework I liked. But this is a full-stack framework itself.

Is there the implementation of AOP pattern for Yii 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually use [Logging](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-logging.html) to profile my code.

```
Yii::trace('starting some event');
foreach(..)
{
    ...
}
Yii::trace('some event done');
```

This traces can be found in the Logs section of the debug bar.

This could be used in combination with [beforeAction()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-controller.html#beforeAction()-detail) and [afterAction()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-controller.html#afterAction()-detail) (not tested)

```
public function beforeAction($action)
{

    if (!parent::beforeAction($action)) {
        return false;
    }

    Yii::trace($action->id.' started');

    return true; // or false to not run the action
}

public function afterAction($action, $result)
{
    $result = parent::afterAction($action, $result);
    Yii::trace($action->id.' ended');
    return $result;
}
```

I also found  [Performance Profiling](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-performance-tuning.html#performance-profiling) in the docs, but i have not tried any of the solutions.